# Aggregate overlapping intervals using data table

Tags: r, data.table, intervals

I have some sample data, where there is (faulty) overlapping intervals, so I would like to split the data into non-overlapping intervals, adding data to each intervals according to the original data.

Assume i have a data table like this:

```
x <- c(1000, 2000, 2000, 1000, 1500)
y <- c(1200, 3000, 4000, 2000, 3000)
z <- c("a", "a", "a", "b", "b")
n1 <- 1:5
n2 <- 4:8

DT <- data.table(id=z,
           start=as.POSIXct(x, origin = "2016-01-01"), 
           end=as.POSIXct(y, origin = "2016-01-01"),
           x=x,
           y=y,
           data1=n1,
           data2=n2)

DT

   id               start                 end    x    y data1 data2
1:  a 2016-01-01 01:16:40 2016-01-01 01:20:00 1000 1200     1     4
2:  a 2016-01-01 01:33:20 2016-01-01 01:50:00 2000 3000     2     5
3:  a 2016-01-01 01:33:20 2016-01-01 02:06:40 2000 4000     3     6
4:  b 2016-01-01 01:16:40 2016-01-01 01:33:20 1000 2000     4     7
5:  b 2016-01-01 01:25:00 2016-01-01 01:50:00 1500 3000     5     8
```

for each id i would like to aggregate the data, using the sum of data within each interval. For `id==a`, it would look like this:

```
1:  a 2016-01-01 01:16:40 2016-01-01 01:20:00 1000 1200     1     4
2:  a 2016-01-01 01:33:20 2016-01-01 01:50:00 2000 3000     3.5   8
3:  a 2016-01-01 01:50:01 2016-01-01 02:06:40 3001 4000     1.5   3
```

Since half of row 3 would be added to row 2. For `id=="b"`, it gets a little more complicated:

```
4:  b 2016-01-01 01:16:40 2016-01-01 01:24:59 1000 1499     2     3.5
5:  b 2016-01-01 01:25:00 2016-01-01 01:33:20 1500 2000     3.67  6.16
6:  b 2016-01-01 01:33:21 2016-01-01 01:50:00 2001 3000     3.33  5.33
```

Here an extra row is added, since we have three different times. the data is divided into each row according to how much was in there in the original interval. For example `DT$data1[5]` is calculated as `1/2 * 4 + 1/3 * 5`.

I assume you could use foverlaps in data.table, but I don't really see how. Please help.

Comment: Do you accept `dplyr` solution ?>_<

Comment: Sure. As long as it works

Comment: Why should `DT$data1[5]` be `1/2 * 4 + 1/3 * 5` and not `1/2 * 4 + 1/2 * 5`. In other words, why should the weights not sum to one and not be half each as both have "half" (almost) of the period?

Comment: Further, how do you decide if you subtract one from the new `y` column or add one to the new `x` column?

Answer (score 1):

It is not clear to me how the logic works with the weights or how to subtract or add to the start and stop times. However, you may find the `data.table` here useful to get to the final tabel you need:

```
> (unique_times <- DT[
+   , .(times = sort(unique(c(x, y)))), by = id][
+     , `:=`(new_start = times, new_end = shift(times, type = "lead")), 
+     by = id][
+       !is.na(new_end)][
+         , times := NULL])
> unique_times
   id new_start new_end
1:  a      1000    1200
2:  a      1200    2000
3:  a      2000    3000
4:  a      3000    4000
5:  b      1000    1500
6:  b      1500    2000
7:  b      2000    3000
> 
> # add data1 and data2 and x and y. The later to compute weights later
> unique_times <- unique_times[
+   DT, .(id, x, y, data1, data2, x.new_start, new_end),
+   on = .(id, new_start <= y), allow.cartesian = TRUE][
+     x < new_end & y > x.new_start]
> unique_times
   id    x    y data1 data2 x.new_start new_end
1:  a 1000 1200     1     4        1000    1200
2:  a 2000 3000     2     5        2000    3000
3:  a 2000 4000     3     6        2000    3000
4:  a 2000 4000     3     6        3000    4000
5:  b 1000 2000     4     7        1000    1500
6:  b 1000 2000     4     7        1500    2000
7:  b 1500 3000     5     8        1500    2000
8:  b 1500 3000     5     8        2000    3000
```

I figure the last step can be made with `by` argument using `id`, `x.new_start` and `new_end`.

Comment: We can avoid the double use of `[.data.table` in the end if there is a way to do an `or` condition instead of an `and` condition with the `on` argument. I did not find a way to do so quickly when I wrote the answer. The intermediate `data.table` may become large with a lot of redundant rows. This may be an issue.